# how to know how many subnets there are in a network

Tags: networking, subnet

Is there any way to know how many subnets there are in a network? or any way to know the mask of an IP? I'm trying to do a network scanner to know the state of the network and I want to include the number of subnets. I searched some information about nmap but I don't found anything

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can infer the shape of a network by watching details of traffic, but judging by the amount of information you appear to be starting with and effort you've put into the question, the answer is many times more advanced than you are prepared for. Most reliably, you would ask routers for this information.

Comment: You could start by making a DHCP request, and inspecting the information the network offers you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, it's impossible to determine the subnet mask or number of subnets in a network just by an IP address.

If you're able to capture network traffic (using Wireshark for example) you could filter and analyze the data and try to figure the subnet mask or amount of subnets per network. It does require quite a bit of knowledge and skills.

Comment: Nothing is "impossible" :)

Comment: @shannon, it is when it comes to subnetting :P You can make wild guesses and assumptions, but you'll never be sure. That's why I added the link for RFC 1918, which shows the default subnet masks for private ranges.

Comment: You could watch broadcasts for all sorts of information. Scanning with ARP easily determines the probable mask. You could probe with traceroutes to determine the number of hops to destinations quite reliably, and make statistically sound assessments about differences in physical distance based on timing. You might be able to actually query network shape from routers. The list of techniques to infer network shape goes on.

Comment: If by 'figure out', you mean calculate in a vacuum given only one IP address, of course. But the OP said he/she is building a scanner. It's quite common for network infrastructure devices and clients to be put at opposite ends of a network. Making a DHCP request will often return the mask which you mentioned is impossible to 'figure out'.

Comment: @shannon, didn't see she said she was using a scanner. Well capturing the stream using Wireshark would definitely provide sufficient information. I'll edit my answer.